# Как корректно выйти из домена в Windows?

Tags: windows, домен, администрирование

Собственно сабж...имеется машинка, которая состоит в определенном домене. Необходимо корректно вывести машинку из этого домена и перевести ее в рабочую группу, при этом сохранив данные учетной записи (избранное, мои документы, рабочий стол и т.д.). Как это можно сделать?

Для справки: машинка на Windows XP.

Answer (score 6):

Корректно вывести ПК из домена можно тем же путем, что и ввести в домен - в свойствах системы, указав, что ПК является членом рабочей группы.
Что касается профиля пользователя, то можно воспользоваться программой ProfileWizard - она не переносит данные из одной учетной записи в другую (локальной папки учетной записи в другую), а заменяет пути и разрешения для целевой учетной записи таким образом, что эта учетная запись использует локальную папку профиля уже существующей учетки (надеюсь понятно написал :))
Ссылка на [ProfileWizard](http://www.forensit.com/ru/downloads.html)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, для "пользователя в домене" создается свой профиль. Отличный от профиля обычного юзера. Поэтому, если вы даже выведете машину из домена в рабочую группу, просто перевести юзера из домена не получится.

Впрочем, у меня срабатывал вариант - при отсутствии доступа к домену, как таковому, вход по "юзеру из домена" все равно возможен на локальной машине.

Если же вас именно это не устраивает и хочется просто иметь юзера на локальной машине из рабочей группы, то можно его создать, перенести соответсвующие документы из папки доменного юзера в папку обычного, и по необходимости - изменить владельца и права доступа к документам. Учтите, что переносить и менять права придется все равно придется: 1. действуя под админом.  2. Исключая использование проводника (он весьма трепетно относится к работе с системными папками), заменив его тоталкоммандером или far.